# How to set up an excel formula to calculate when a condition is met, while preserving historical data?

Tags: excel

So here is my dilemma. I need to use a vlookup in order to populate a cell with a number, but I only want it to do that when a condition is met. For instance when A3=X update the formula. The kicker is is that I can't use the excel menu or a macro, or otherwise I would use the manual calculation or setup a macro. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I need the vlookup up to run then hold that value once the condition is met. What I am trying to accomplish is to set up a rate table that works using a vlookup on a table that is updated through SQL. But I want to preserve the historical data and tell it when to update. So replacing it with static information would not work as suggested in the comments.

Comment: no, formulas are live data, and you can choose to show a static variable: `=IF(A3<>"X","wait",VLOOKUP(...))` but you cannot keep the VLOOKUP return static till you put an X in a cell without turning off the calculations and/or using vba.

Comment: Just make the formula return some **default** value if the condition is **not** true.

Comment: I guess my explanation wasn't good enough. I need the vlookup up to run then hold that value once the condition is met. What I am trying to accomplish is to set up a rate table that works using a vlookup on a table that is updated through SQL. But I want to preserve the historical data and tell it when to update.